# search in react + redux

Tags: javascript, api, reactjs, redux

There is an application written on React + Redux. There is an input field (search) and, when entered, the function of requesting data via api is called. The response time from the server is approximately 2.5 seconds. If a user enters a search string quickly, then data does not arrive from the server. I did a search for the click. How to organize the search correctly?

Comment: What have you done so far to solve it? Please provide the code and mention where and what exact error are you getting

Comment: Your question might be a little bit too general in order to provide you some useful answers. Is it about how to deal with a "pending" status, for instance showing a spinner while the results/suggestions are loading ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use something called a debounce or a throttle function to make sure you only search once every x milliseconds. `lodash` has implementations of both ([debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce), [throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#throttle)), but writing your own is also pretty fun :)